# Constraining a generic initilizer parameter to class generic type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to implement a type erasing wrapper for a protocol. I have a protocol with an associatedtype constrainted to `CaseIterable` and a method using that type.

Given the following definitions:

```swift
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype A: CaseIterable
    
    func doSomething(input: A)
}

final class AnyFoo<A: CaseIterable>: Foo {
    private let _doSomething: (A) -> Void

    init<Other: Foo>(wrappedFoo: Other) where Other.A == A {
        // "Cannot assign value of type '(Other.A) -> ()' to type '(A) -> Void'"
        _doSomething = wrappedFoo.doSomething(input:)
    }
  
    func doSomething(input: A) {
        _doSomething(input)
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error `Cannot assign value of type '(Other.A) -> ()' to type '(A) -> Void'` in the initializer of the class. It seems that the compiler interprets `A` and `Other.A` as different types, and I can't figure out why, because the initializer has constrained `Other.A` and `A` to be the same. If I replace `CaseIterable` with `Hashable`, there's no problem.

Can somebody explain why this is happening?

Comment: This is a bug in the 13.4.1 compiler (it actually crashes the compiler). It's resolved in 14.

Comment: Our team reported some related trouble with CaseIterable here: https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/58346

Answer (score -2):

Of course you can't. The `_doSomething` in class `AnyFoo` is type of `Block`  which is an **Anonymous function**. So you can assign `wrappedFoo.doSomething(input:)` to it. When you call `_doSomething(input)`, it actually call `wrappedFoo.doSomething(input: input)`.

In another way, you can define a `Block` like:

```
let completion: (bool) -> void = { finished in
}
```

but you can't define it like:

```
let completion: (true) -> void = { finished in
}
```